# DAX Measure displaying values only for certain combination

Tags: visual-studio, pivot-table, dax, sql-server-data-tools, measure

setting up a SSDT in Visual Studio where I have masterlist with prices and 3 addtional attributes. These 3 attributes (Region, Customer, Material) can be used to to link the data to the other table with all the sales information etc.

Target: Showing the prices in a pivot if the 3 attributes are fulfilled and are matching to the other table with the same attribute combination. Assuming a calculated column is not solving the problem as this cannot display the price values in the value section of the pivot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8B8lx.png)

Please help me to find an appropriate DAX measure to link the data and show the prices for the matching attribute combination.

Thanks in advance :)

Masterlist with attributes which can be used as a key to connect to the other list?

Comment: Can you please share some sample data and what is the expected result?

Comment: See sample data in post. Finally result is to display the Price in the Pivot when dragging this criteria to the values list.